# laravel select required not working

Tags: php, jquery, html, laravel

I want the user make a selects in select before proceeding to the next step. But it does not work!

```
{!! Form::select('lists', [''=> ''] + $metiers, null, ['id'=>'list', 'required', 'class' => 'form-control', 'scrollbar', 'name'=>'list']) !!}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
{!! Form::select('lists', [''=> ''] + $metiers, null, ['id'=>'list', 'required' => 'required', 'class' => 'form-control', 'scrollbar', 'name'=>'list']) !!}
```